# MongoDB Reuse _id

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a simple schema for `Users`, which gets an automatically generated `_id`:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("9dfhdf9fdhd90dfdhdaf"),
  name: "Joe Shmoe"
}
```

And then I have a schema for `Groups` where I can add `Users` into a members array.

```
{
  name: "Joe's Group",
  members: [{
    _id: ObjectId("58fdaffdhfd9fdsahfdsfa"),
    name: "Joe Shmoe"
  }]
}
```

Objects within an array get new autogenerated IDs, but I'd like to keep that `_id` field consistent and reuse it so that the member in the `Group` has the same attributes as they do in the `Users` collection.

My obvious solution is to create an independent `id` field in the members' `User` object that references their `_id` in the `Users` collection, but that seems cluttered having two separate id fields for each member.

My question is, is what I'm attempting bad practice? What's the *correct* way to add existing objects into a collection from another collection?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're referring to is : manual or DB References in data modelling.

```
original_id = ObjectId()

db.places.insert({
    "_id": original_id,
    "name": "Broadway Center",
    "url": "bc.example.net"
})

db.people.insert({
    "name": "Erin",
    "places_id": original_id,
    "url":  "bc.example.net/Erin"
})
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references)

Comment: Thank you, but I actually literally not five minutes ago just finally figured out how to use populate with Mongoose which was exactly what I needed. Was planning on throwing an answer to my own question up first thing in the morning.